# VirtualBox - Python

Tags: python-3.x, api, virtualbox, kvm

Всем доброго времени суток! Ищу некое API для автоматизации работы с виртуальными машинами(желательно VB) силами Python. Интересует именно работа со снимками виртуальной машины. Нигде не могу найти подобное

Comment: Думаю, можно просто команду VBoxManage из питона запускать

Comment: @andreymal Благодарю Вас!